# iPhone - How to read headingAccuracy to use magneticHeading and trueHeading?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, core-location, heading

When CLHeading `headingAccuracy` property is negative, does that mean that `magneticHeading` is invalid, does that mean that `trueHeading` is invalid, or does that mean that both headings are invalid ?

I mean, as far as I understand, `magneticHeading` is hardware dependent, and `trueHeading` depends on the availability of a GPS position. If there are no GPS position, I guess `trueHeading` cannot be computed, so `headingAccuracy` should be -1, with a possibly correct `magneticHeading` (magnetometer doe not depend on a GPS). On the other hand, if `headingAccuracy` = -1, that could mean that both are incorrect : problem of magnetometer and possibly GPS error.

So... If I'm correct, there are cases where `headingAccuracy` is 1 and `magneticHeading` is correct.

The doc is not clear on that point.

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLHeading_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/CLHeading/headingAccuracy) says it applies to the magneticHeading: `represents the potential error between the value reported by the magneticHeading property and the actual direction of magnetic north`

However, it really applies to both.  The magnetic heading is measuring using the onboard magnetometers.  The true heading is computed by adding (or subtracting) the [magnetic declination](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetic_declination) for your current location to the measured magnetic heading.  Any errors in the magnetic heading measurement will also cause the same error in the true heading.

Comment: ok, but as far as I understand, magnticHeading is hardware dependent, and trueHeading depends on the availability of a GPS position. If there are no GPS position, I guess trueheading cannot be computed, so headingAccuracy should be -1, with a possibly correct magneticHeading. On the otherhand, if headingAccuracy = -1, that could mean that both are incorrect. So... If I'm correct, there are cases where headingAccuracy  == 1 and magneticHeading is correct. Did I miss something ?